# "None" when trying to graph in Django with Networkx

Tags: python, django, networkx, graphing

I'm currently working on a project that requires connected nodes. I've tried finding some decent Python graphing tools and arrived at Networkx. Say that I have an office, and this office has several departments with employees. I'd like the employees to be connected to the department, but first of all I'm just trying to show the departments.

```
def department(request):
    context=RequestContext(request)
    G = nx.Graph()
    deps= models.Department.objects.all()
    for d in deps:
        G.add_node(d)
    return HttpResponse(nx.draw_circular(G))
```

However, this just gives me a "None" when I try to run it. There are currently two departments in my database. Does anyone have any ideas? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The draw functions don't return anything, which is why you get `None` as the output, since that's what you're passing to HttpResponse. I don't know enough about the library to know what they do with the results, though.

Comment: Tell us what is that you want exactly to view in your response. The `draw` functions in `networkx` are supposed to be used with `matplotlib` so I frankly doubt you can use them to get a view of the graph in an `HttpResponse`. Do you just want the list of edges?

Comment: What I'd like as a result is a node (represented as a circle) that has the name of the departments written in/underneath it. When I click that node, I can see other connected nodes that represent the employee, but I'd be glad to get just this working for now

Comment: You'll need to work a lot more than that to get there. For now, I say you might want to save the network view as `png` somewhere with `savefig` and then render the `png`. Docs: http://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/tutorial/tutorial.html#drawing-graphs

Comment: Ah, right. Do you know of an easier way to do it? Maybe just pass the objects in Django and do the visualization with JS? Many thanks for your reply :)